# Can I combine 2 cucumber reports generated by 2 Runners into a single one

Tags: parallel-processing, cucumber, reporting, karate

I am trying to find a way to combine 2 test reports in one, so that I can run 2 levels of tests in the same call. As far as I can see it seems Features are always run in paralell and "parallel=false" only applies to scenarios and I want to run some in sequence and some in parallel.
It would be something like this :

```
public void testParallel() {
    Results results1 = Runner.path("classpath:testone").tags("~@ignore").parallel(0);
    Results results2 = Runner.path("classpath:testtwo").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
    # Combine 2 results here
    Result = results1 + results2 (or concat, or whatever is correct)
    # then generate global report
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
  }

Any help appreciated
Thanks ;-)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options:

- refactor your tests to be in the same single `Scenario` (recommended)
- refactor your tests to be in the same single `Feature` + `@parallel=false` tag
- write a new Feature and do a `call` to the `Scenario`-s [by tag](https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector), note that once you enter a `call` everything is on the same thread as the "caller"

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Peter !! ;-)

Comment: #1 is not possible. I am testing all endpoints of an Api, that can't be one scenario.
#2 I have thought about and is an ok option, except I wanted to keep endpoints separated by .feature ... but it's an option
#3 I will give that a try, That would keep all features separated. 

Would be great if you could implement the parallel=false by feature though :-)
Thanks

Comment: @user1991463 would be great if you submit a PR ;)

Comment: Hi Peter, You mean submit a "feature request" ?