# Running multiple feature files for multiple users in a single runner

Tags: karate

Curious if there is a built-in method or best practice to run multiple feature files (say 30) against different user account regions (say 10 - currently we have this based on a karate parameter (dsRow) passed in mvn cmd line) within a single runner.

Should we simply make 10 runners, 1 for each region, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

This is desired rather than duplicating all the feature files for each user independently, as the responses are all the same, so no difference in assertions, but we want to ensure that all calls work the same across all our user account regions.  We are looking to do this to ensure items that may be distributed to a specific region during BETA testing is available to all regions after general release and no areas are inadvertently missed.

### Response to suggested duplicate

The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387798/how-can-we-execute-webui-feature-file-against-multiple-browsers-using-parallel-r) points out using Scenario Outlines, but that is not an option as our feature files already include these.  To expand on this, we currently have 83 feature files with 1035 scenarios, mainly outlines, that we run against a single user (account region).  Since each user has to go through the authentication process, doing that repeatedly during each scenario seems like excessive overkill rather than repeating all test at a runner level for the desired user.

To simply recreate and maintain all these tests across all the different regions would be a nightmare, which is why we created user accounts specific to each reason.  Now, the question is how can we loop through those using a runner.  If a scenario outline is proposed, how can we compile an outline of a feature file list, and still maintain reporting at the individual scenario level however, I believe this is NOT recommended, based on the [linked post from the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684630/how-to-prepare-a-nested-data-structure-for-a-data-driven-test-in-karate/61685169#61685169) post.

Comment: This post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370756/can-i-combine-2-cucumber-reports-generated-by-2-runners-into-a-single-one, represents more of what we are trying to do, then the duplicate post around scenarios, referenced. However, the only option that would work for us is #3, but that would eliminate the report details for individual scenarios and combine everything under the "caller", calling feature file